# Python 3 - Having 2 items as 1 index in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ37t.png)

I am new to python and I am trying to build a quiz thingy.
And so one of the questions contain 2 answers to it but I cant figure out how to accept both of the answers. As shown in the pic, I want to have both 'this' and 'that' to be acceptable as an answer. Is there a way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

```
questions_asked = [
    "Q1",
    "Q2",
]

answers = [
    "Answer",
    "This" or "That"
]


def run_question():
    score = 0
    index = 0
    for question in questions_asked:
        if index < len(questions_asked):
            answer = input(questions_asked[index]).lower()

            if answer == answers[index].lower():
                score += 1
        index += 1
    print("{score} out of 2".format(score=score))


run_question()
```

Comment: Use a `set` to hold acceptable answers, then use `in` to check if the user's input is in the `set`.  O(1) inclusion checking

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why would you include a picture of your code when you could have copy/pasted it?>

Comment: You should copy paste the code directly so we can play with it. Its better.

Comment: Please add code, error logs and any relevant info as text. Trying and replicating your problem is troublesome from an image.

Comment: @dfundako I didn't know how to do so before.... but now i do XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your data structure. Rather than a `answers: List[str]`, you should use `answers: List[set]`

```
answers = [{"one answer"}, {"another answer"}, {"a couple", "correct answers"}]
```

Then you can check it with:

```
expected = answers[i]  # however you're doing this -- I'd probably zip it together
                       # with questions, but YMMV
if user_answer in expected:
    # correct
```

---

Note that your loop can be greatly simplified:

```
score = 0
for question, expected_answers in zip(questions_asked, answers):
    user_answer = input(question).lower()
    if user_answer in expected_answers:
        score += 1
```

Comment: Still don't think is the best way to approach this.  A dictionary of sets seems like a much better data structure to use for this type of thing.  I don't see a good reason to keep questions and answers stored separately.

Comment: @user3483203 agreed, but I didn't want to deviate too far from the OP's code. I'd prefer a `List[Tuple[str, set]]` given my druthers, but a dict is just as good I suppose

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for your help. I'll look through zips and dicts too

Comment: @AfkAlpha zips are very helpful. You specify two lists (well, two of any iterable, actually) and it produces a *new* iterable that loops over both of them at once, so `zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']) -> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`. (That's slightly oversimplifying since `zip` doesn't produce a list, but that's the result you'll get!)

Comment: @AfkAlpha you can use it to finagle some fairly complicated behavior in easily-understandable ways, and there's also a couple Python idioms that make heavy use of `zip` (e.g. `zip(*some_2D_list)` changes its indexing from row-wise to column-wise)

Comment: @AdamSmith Wow, i only watched some beginner tutorials on YT hence i never knew about zips. But by reading what you said, it seems easy to use. Except for the row and column thing... how does that work? Does it only return one value? like in your example, normally index 0 gives (1,a), so column gives...1? Idk lol

Comment: @AfkAlpha [here's an example](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/a7057c369557e58857dda69185493a49)

Comment: @AdamSmith Ohhh i get it! Well there's so much for me to learn and explore

Answer (score 0):

Or make your "answers" as dictionaries.

```
dict = {'answer1': 'this', 'answer2': 'that', 'answer3': 'None'}
```

[link for dictionary manipulation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)